# Call to IAM API in Lambda times out

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a NodeJS lambda function that is trying to list IAM users via the IAM [listUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#listUsers-property) API method .  The call is firing off but never returning until the lambda function itself times out and I'm unsure why.  Here is the code:

```js
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
        console.log('before call');
        var ret = await listIAMUsers();
        console.log('ret: ' + JSON.stringify(ret));
    };
    
    
    async function listIAMUsers() {
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});
        var iam = new AWS.IAM({apiVersion: '2010-05-08'});
        
        var params = {MaxItems: 10};
        
        return iam.listUsers(params).promise();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Managing IAM Users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/iam-examples-managing-users.html). Pay close attention where we initialize the client and add require statements.

For the optimization purpose. it is good to load and initialize the. client while loading the function

```js
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});
// Create the IAM service object
var iam = new AWS.IAM({apiVersion: '2010-05-08'});
```

As JS is single-threaded so you reuse the clients.

```js
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
        console.log('before call');
        var ret = await listIAMUsers();
        console.log('ret: ' + JSON.stringify(ret));
};
    
async function listIAMUsers() {
    // Set the region 
    AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});
    // Create the IAM service object
    var iam = new AWS.IAM({apiVersion: '2010-05-08'});
    var params = {MaxItems: 10};
    return iam.listUsers(params).promise();
}
```

```
START RequestId: 933ca3dd-2feb-4f98-8f8e-87286f59748d Version: $LATEST
2021-02-22T15:57:14.867Z    933ca3dd-2feb-4f98-8f8e-87286f59748d    INFO    before call
2021-02-22T15:57:15.560Z    933ca3dd-2feb-4f98-8f8e-87286f59748d    INFO    ret: {"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"bf65a9f5-e4a6-493b-a6a2-c3081d88f7be"},
"Users":[
    {"Path":"/","UserName":"username","UserId":"sadsadsadsa",
"Arn":"arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/username",
"CreateDate":"2020-11-27T13:09:20.000Z","Tags":[]},
    {"Path":"/","UserName":"tempuser","UserId":"adsadasdasdsad",
"Arn":"arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/tempuser",
"CreateDate":"2021-01-24T21:24:47.000Z","Tags":[]}],"IsTruncated":false}
END RequestId: 933ca3dd-2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately after moving that require statement around it is still failing with the same behavior of  timing out when the lambda times out

Comment: @ChrisDellinger the code I shared is a working one,  just try copy-pasting it should work, plus check your `handler`. settings in the lambda settings if it is set correctly. Plus make sure if your lambda role has the necessary permissions to list the users. If. possible you can share the error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here:

1. Lambda Role Permission - Try to check if your lambda role is attached with the correct IAM Policy such as `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMReadOnlyAccess`
2. If your Lambda function is placed within a Public Subnet or Private Subnet without any internet access, you would require `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` attached as well as the internet or aws services access (shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html))